# Linux Mint: pastebin is in /usr/local/bin

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, security

I'm running Linux Mint 17.

I found a *pastebin* python file in `/usr/local/bin`

In light of what people use pastebin for, was this a security risk?

[image]

Output from the `stat` command:

```
  File: ‘pastebin’
  Size: 576         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fc01h/64513d    Inode: 5768847     Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2016-01-19 10:43:31.595833213 -0500
Modify: 2015-02-03 07:15:10.000000000 -0500
Change: 2016-01-19 10:43:30.575833252 -0500
 Birth: -
```

It is believed the pastebin was put there by the original distro. Related discussion here [Distro invades '/usr/local'](https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1399934).

Comment: this might be a better question for folks who deal with this distro

Answer (score 1):

Whether it's in `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/bin` is irrelevant.
It's just a python script that posts either its arguments or its STDIN to a web service:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import sys, os, stat, subprocess

content = ""

mode = os.fstat(0).st_mode
if stat.S_ISFIFO(mode):
    content = sys.stdin.read()
elif stat.S_ISREG(mode):
    content = sys.stdin.read()
else:
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    if len(args) == 1 and os.path.exists(args[0]):
        with open(args[0], 'r') as infile:
            content = infile.read()
    else:
        str_args = ' '.join(args)
        content = str_args

if content != "":
    p = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/nc", "paste.linuxmint.com", "9999"], stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
    p.communicate(content)
```

If your users have Internet access, `pastebin` doesn't allow them to do anything more than what they already can do.

BTW, isn't it nice that `bash` allows you to compress the above ugly pythonese to just?:

```
/bin/nc paste.linuxmint.com 9999 <<< "${*:-`cat`}"
```

(It won't behave completely identically, but it shouldn't matter.)

Comment: That isn't `bash(1)`'s doing, just one of the uses of the network Swiss army knife toolbox `netcat(1)` ;-)

Comment: @vonbrand The python script runs the very same netcat command.